# Disable horizontal scroll and bounce on IOS without overflow hidden

Tags: css, ios, scroll

I am trying to find way to disable horizontal scrolling/bounce effect on IOS. I searched a lot but can't find any solution. It is hard to believe there can't be anything done about it.

I can't set overflow hidden because I am using sticky position elements. Would be great if someone has solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, you need to unset any width like 100vw and make sure any child element's aren't overflowing. It will disable bounce.